# array.Max(); for the array index rather than the value

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating an array that will take in 24 numbers and display them in a table. I have used "arrayname".Max(); to determine the highest number but I need to display the array slot with the highest number

e.g. hour 15 had the highest number so 15 will displayed in a message rather than the number assigned to 15.

My code is as follows:

```
 public void busiest(int[] A)
 {
     int busy;
     busy = A.Max(); //Displays the highest values in a given set i.e. an array
     Console.WriteLine("\nThe busiest time of day was hour " + busy);
 }
```

Could anyone say if i'm missing something simple to display the slot rather than the assigned number?

Thanks

Comment: When you say slot do you mean the index?  Are you trying to find which index/position in the array corresponds to the highest number?

Comment: Yes, sorry, keep calling it a slot

Comment: Will your array ever have duplicate values?  Meaning, if you have two items in the array that happen to be the max, is the order important?

Comment: No, the order is not important

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That you need to call is `Array.IndexOf`:

```
Array.IndexOf(A, A.Max());
```

For further info regarding this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Beware that if there are more than one elements in the array with the same value, the index of the first of them would be returned from this method. For instance if the maximum value is 10 and there are two elements one at position with index 2 and one at position with index 3, then this method would return the value of 2.

Comment: @William.Foster No problem:)